# How do i show results in mysql column when other column is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    (IFNULL(daily_clicks, 0)), 
    (IFNULL(daily_score, 0)), 
    (SELECT SUM(`daily_score`) FROM `user_score` `n`) AS total 
FROM
`user_score` `t` WHERE `userid`="123123" AND t.created='2015-06-27' LIMIT 1;
```

If i change the date to where data exist i see the total user_score, but when i select where there are no results for that specific date, i get nothing back (even in the sum).

How do i get the sum column to appear even if other does not?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date doesn't exist, then the query returns no rows.

One method is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(daily_clicks), 0), 
       coalesce(sum(daily_score), 0)
FROM `user_score` `t`
WHERE `userid` = 123123 AND t.created = '2015-06-27';
```

This will guarantee that one row returns, even when there are no matches.  If you want each `daily_click`, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT group_concat(daily_clicks),
       coalesce(sum(daily_score), 0)
FROM `user_score` `t`
WHERE `userid` = 123123 AND t.created = '2015-06-27';
```

This still returns one row, but with multiple `daily_clicks` values concatenated in one column.